# Creating a Job Log using Case and dates

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a code use for creating a data base and calendar inside google sheets. The problem is using the switch function. Only the first case works.

I tried using If Else and again. Only the code work with the compareDates = to 0. The switch function is supposed to take the values from the data base (in a sheet) and take it to the weekly calendar.

Please help me with this.

```
function jobLogSchedule() {
    var ss        = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();/// Activate Sheet Application
    var formSS    = ss.getSheetByName("Form"); //Form Sheet
    var dataBase  = ss.getSheetByName("Data"); //Data Sheet  

    var viewSchedule = formSS.getRange("B20").getValue();
    var firstDate = new Date(viewSchedule);

    formSS.getRange("H2" && "H4").setValue(firstDate);
    var lastRow = dataBase.getLastRow();
    var counterColumn = 10;
    var counterRow1stDay = 4;
    var counterRow2stDay = 14;
    var counterRow3stDay = 24;
    var counterRow4stDay = 34;  
    var counterRow5stDay = 44;
    var counterRow6stDay = 54;
    var counterRow7stDay = 64;

    for (i = 2; i < lastRow + 1; i++) {
        var dateColumn = dataBase.getRange(i,6,lastRow).getValue();
        var dateDataBase = new Date(dateColumn);
        var valuesForCalendar = [[
            dataBase.getRange(i, 1).getValue(),
            dataBase.getRange(i, 2).getValue(),
            dataBase.getRange(i, 3).getValue(),
            dataBase.getRange(i, 4).getValue(),
            dataBase.getRange(i, 5).getValue(),
            dataBase.getRange(i, 6).getValue(),
        ]];

        var compareDates = dateDataBase - firstDate;

        switch (compareDates) {
        case 0:
            formSS.getRange(counterRow1stDay, counterColumn, 1, 6).setValues(valuesForCalendar);
            counterRow1stDay = counterRow1stDay + 1;
            break;
        case 1:
            formSS.getRange(counterRow2stDay, counterColumn, 1, 6).setValues(valuesForCalendar);
            counterRow2stDay = counterRow2stDay + 1;
            break;
        case 2:
            formSS.getRange(counterRow3stDay, counterColumn, 1, 6).setValues(valuesForCalendar);
            counterRow3stDay = counterRow3stDay + 1;
            break;
        case 3:
            formSS.getRange(counterRow4stDay, counterColumn, 1, 6).setValues(valuesForCalendar);
            counterRow4stDay = counterRow4stDay + 1;
            break;
        case 4:
            formSS.getRange(counterRow5stDay, counterColumn, 1, 6).setValues(valuesForCalendar);
            counterRow5stDay = counterRow5stDay + 1;
            break;
        case 5:
            formSS.getRange(counterRow6stDay, counterColumn, 1, 6).setValues(valuesForCalendar);                  
            counterRow6stDay = counterRow6stDay + 1;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What are the numbers for the Case function? Days?
As @IVO  GELOV [said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57302108/creating-a-job-log-using-case-and-dates#answer-57303625), you need to calculate the milliseconds and then use the differences in the case.

Answer (score 1):

Date objects do not support the subtraction operation. You will have to first extract the dates as UNIX timestamp values in milliseconds and subtract them:

```
var compareDates = dateDataBase.getTime() - firstDate.getTime();
```